# conexión mysql con java

Tags: java

Buen día estoy siguiendo un ejemplo que conseguí en la red para poder contarme a una base de datos pero  tengo problemas con la conexión a MySQL desde java

El sistema me envié el siguiente error .

si hago clic en (conexion.java.82) el cursor se dirige a la línea

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM persona");
```

[image: mensaje de error]

el  código es el siguiente

```
 package app;

import static app.conexion.getConection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connectio
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author gpbrandi
 */
public class conexion extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final String URL = "jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/Escuela";
    public static final String USERNAME = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "mysql";

    private static void cach() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public conexion() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("CONECTAR");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            con = getConection();

        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet res;

        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM persona");
        res = (ResultSet) ps.executeQuery();

        if(res.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resgetString("nombre") + " " + res.getString("domicilio"));
        } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Existe Datos");
        }
        con.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }                                        

    public static Connection getConection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion EXITOSA");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return con;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new conexion().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private String resgetString(String nombre) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Agradezco si me puede orientar en donde esta mi error
Soy nuevo programando en Java anteriormente programaba en VB y llegue a las conexión con base de datos pero aquí llevo semanas estancado

Comment: No cambies tu pregunta, si tienes otro problema crea otra pregunta si no esta queda totalmente sin sentido.

Comment: He revertido a la versión original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por el error que muestra al comienzo:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Es un error netamente al buscar la clase que realiza la conexión con la base de datos, en esta línea:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

Lo cual desencadena los demás errores, al tratar de buscar en una base de datos, la cual no se ha podido realizar la conexión de manera correcta.

---

Lo anterior puede suceder por dos razones (en su mayoría):

*1. Se ha escrito de manera incorrecta el nombre los packages o de la clase necesaria para crear la correcta conexión con la base de datos **"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"***

*2. La clase no se encuentra, porque probablemente no se ha añadido la librería correspondiente, para realizar la conexión con la base de datos (para realizar la conexión con MySQL, se necesita la librería **MySQL JDBC Driver**)*

---

Por lo que puedo observar es que dentro del nombre que tienes, para llamar a la clase que realiza la conexión, una letra se encuentra escrita en minúscula, debemos recordar que Java es bastante tajante con la diferencia entre minúsculas y mayúsculas, por lo que debería ser:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

> Driver debería tener la letra "d", en mayúscula, ya que hace
>   referencia a una clase, y las clases en Java deben de nombrarse con la
>   primera letra en mayúscula

De esta manera puedes llamar correctamente a la librería para usar MySQL

Te dejo un [tutorial](http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/08/conectar-base-de-datos-mysql-con-java.html) de como realizar la conexión a una base de datos MySQL con Java en español con JDBC

Comment: Muchas Gracias voy a intentar con la soluciónn que me indicas .

Comment: Si la respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, por otra parte hago una acotación a tu código, la clase **conexion** que muestras debe de ir con la primera letra del nombre en mayúscula _Conexion_ es solamente para respetar las buenas prácticas de programación en Java, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias todo funciono bien , he seguido avanzando y ahora me encuentro con el siguiente error , el programa BUSCA,MODIFICA,ELIMINA,LIMPIA los datos sin problema pero cuando trato de guardar me envie el siguiente mensaje

run: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

podría orientarme en cual puede ser el problema

Comment: Añade el código de tu programa en tu pregunta, existe la opción **editar**

Comment: @Riaven no debe añadir el código si no crear una nueva pregunta. Lo que ha hecho deja inutilizada la pregunta y tu respuesta.

Comment: @GiuseppeBrandi, si la respuesta de Riaven te ha servido deberías de aceptarla.

Comment: Disculpen soy nuevo en el Foro y no veo donde aceptar la respuesta, agardezco su ayuda

Comment: @JDev tiene razón, puedes crear una nueva pregunta con el problema que te ha surgido ahora, con respecto a donde aceptar la respuesta, al costado izquierdo de la misma, se encuentra la zona para votar a favor o en contra, debajo de eso hay una especie de tic para marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

1. revisa tu linea de codigo:

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

2. Revisa que tengas instalado tu controlador/API/driver/JAR (como lo quieras llamar) en tu proyecto (Dependencias de Java).

Comment: Lo correcto es : Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); como menciona Riaven en su respuesta, saludos.