# Como conectar a mi base de datos en mysql

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mysqlconnector

Estoy realizando mi proyecto en java para conectar a mi base de datos en mysql pero tanto mi servidor como la base de datos tienen usuario y contraseña como pongo para el usuario y contraseña en mi proyecto lo tengo así:

```
private static Connection con;
private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "14785";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://direcciónDeMiServidor:3306/prueba";

public void conector() 
 {
    con = null;
    try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            if (con != null) 
               {
                    jLabel1.setText("Conexion establecida");
               }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) 
        {
             jLabel1.setText("Error de conexion" + e);
        }
}

public conexion() 
{
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [conexión mysql con java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282066/conexi%c3%b3n-mysql-con-java)

Comment: Te esta generando algun error? seria bueno que describieras mejor tu pregunta

Comment: Anexe mi código de la conexión que quiero hacer, mi pregunta es como hacer para también agregar el usuario y la contraseña se mi base de datos y no solo de mi servidor, porque donde hago la conexión solo tengo, url, user, pass